# Unity: Quad does not restart postion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a problem I am not sure how to resolve. I have a Quad with a very long image and a script that makes this whole thing into a scrolling background. The problem is that when my player dies and I restart the game, the quad does not start from the beginning of the image, but rather continue from the point of death. After a few deaths, my player spawns on an empty background, because the Quad image has long finished. I tried destroying it on player death, and it did get destroyed, but after a restart, it still remembered the last position the Quad reached. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

The scrolling code:

```
    void Update () {
        {
            if (!timerReached)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;

                Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
            }


            if (!timerReached && timer > TIMER_TIME)
            {

                timerReached = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have no code that tells your image it should reset.

Comment: @Draco18s I guessed that, but I am not sure how to write it. I tried a few things, but I might be doing something unexpectedly stupid.

Comment: @TheNewbie show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are offsetting your texture using `Time.time`.  This is the seconds since the game started and will never reset to zero but will always be increasing.

Instead, offset your texture using `timer`, which you are already summing with `deltaTime`, and when you die, reset `timer` to zero (which I suspect you already do).

```
timer += Time.deltaTime;

Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, timer * speed);
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
```

Comment: I am not sure I reset it anywhere. That is all the code I wrote above. I tried forcing the timer to 0 somehow, but nothing worked and the Quad still keeps the position from the last time it stopped.